# Docker Swarm Keeps Creating and Shutting Down instances

Tags: docker

I followed the instructions here to set up docker swarm
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part6/#deploy-your-app-on-a-cloud-provider

Connected to the docker swarm. Then yesterday I stopped a few of the instances thinking that I could just restart them the next day to save costs. Instead AWS kept creating and shutting down instances.

I had stopped all the manager and worker nodes.

What's going on? How do I debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker swarm creates 2 autoscaling groups. One for the manager node and one for the worker node. They will spin up new instances and terminate old ones when they find an instance to be unhealthy. Not sure why they found my instances to be unhealthy.

In any case, to stop the instances at night, you have to delete the autoscaling group but then I'm not sure how you'll create a new one other than by deleting everything and following the steps all over again.